# Decide if this subset is a basis of the vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

> Decide if the subset is a basis of the vector space $V$.
>
> $\left\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}\right\} = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1\\  2\\ 
> 1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
> -1\\  3\\  2 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 3\\  1\\ 
> -2 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$ in $V = \mathbb{R}^{3}$

I think an equivalent question would be "Are these three vectors linearly independent?".

So I would write these three vectors as a matrix and then use Sarrus rule to calculate the determinant. If determinant $\neq 0$, then the subset is a basis of the vector space $V$.

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & -1  & 3\\ 
2 &  3  & 1\\ 
1 &  2  & -2
\end{vmatrix}
\begin{matrix}
1 & -1\\ 
2 &  3\\ 
1 &  2
\end{matrix}$$

$$\text{Determinant} = -10$$

Thus the three vectors are linearly independent and this means the subset $\left\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}\right\}$ is a basis of the vector space $V$.

---

Please tell me if I did it correctly and if not how to do it correctly?

Comment: It looks correct.  One note, a basis is a linearly independent set *which spans the space*.  Proving it's linearly independent is generally not sufficient.  But if you know the dimension of the space (3 for $\Bbb R^3$) and your linearly independent set has that same number of vectors (it does in this case), then you can make your conclusion.

Comment: @Bye_World Very good to know, thanks! Will write that to my notes :)

Comment: @Bye_World One more question though. Let's take this example. We have these three vectors and they are all linearly independent. If I write these three vectors as $3 \times 3$ matrix, can I deduce that its dimension will be $3$, since all three are linearly independent?

Comment: Yes.  The determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix is nonzero if and only if its columns are linearly independent.  A set of $n$ linearly independent vectors span a space that has dimension $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is correct.** The definition of linearly independent is, for $v_1,v_2,v_3 \in V = \mathbb{R}^3$ we have that, for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ these vectors are linearly independent if the relation below is true

> $$\alpha v_1 + \beta v_2 + \gamma v_3 = 0 \iff \alpha = \beta = \gamma = 0$$

So, for the vectors pointed out by you in your question you have that

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\alpha - \beta + 3\gamma=0\\ 
2\alpha + 3\beta + \gamma=0\\ 
\alpha + 2\beta - 2\gamma=0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Solving this system is *related* to set the matrix

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & -1  & 3\\ 
2 &  3  & 1\\ 
1 &  2  & -2
\end{matrix}\right)$$

in [row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form). Using linear transformations we get the matrix in the form

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & -1  & 3\\ 
0 &  -5  & 5\\ 
0 &  0  & -2
\end{matrix}\right)$$

Which is *related* to the system

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\alpha - \beta + 3\gamma=0\\ 
-5\beta + 5\gamma=0\\ 
 - 2\gamma=0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

That has only the **trivial solution**. So we can conclude that these vectors are linearly independent. This problem is equivalent to search for the determinant as you did above because it is true that for a [Homogeneous system of equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Homogeneous_systems) that have a related matrix, let's say the $A$ matrix, have only the trivial solution when the determinant is different then zero.